# expected primary-expression before '[' token

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void skaityti(int & n,int & kmLimit,struct mailSend[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct mailSend {
           string name[50];
           int xCoor[50];
           int yCoor[50];
    };
    int n,kmLimit;
    skaityti(n,kmLimit,mailSend[]);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
            cout<<mailSend.name[i]<<mailSend.xCoor[i]<<mailSend.yCoor[i]<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void skaityti(int & n,int & kmLimit,struct mail[])
{
     ifstream fd("U1");
     fd>>n>>kmLimit;
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) fd>>mailSend.name[i]>>mailSend.xCoor[i]>>mailSend.yCoor[i];
     fd.close();
}
```

I have searched for information to deal with this, but couldn't found the answer so decided to ask you guys :).I'm getting a lot of "expected primary-expression before '[' token"or "before '.' token", what's the problem?
The errors are on line 15,18 and 27.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string>`.

Comment: This is not C. So why tag it with `c`?

Comment: Arrays start at 0, too.

Comment: Including string didn't helped.
And about the C, I don't really know the difference between C++ and C. So tagged both so I wouldn't mistag one.

Comment: About the arrays - that's kinda offtopic and it suits me to leave 1st index blank. Let's get back to the topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mailSend` is the name of the struct type, not of a variable.  You can't pass the name of a type as a parameter when it is expecting an array of the type.  You have to declare an array of the `mailSend` that you can pass in to `skaityti()`